# Prove convergence in probabilty

Tags: probability

Let $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of random variables such that:

$$x_n=0 \quad \text{with probability} \quad 1-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n$$
$$x_n=1 \quad \text{with probability} \quad \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n$$

I want to prove that $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ converges in probability and almost surely to zero.

For the first part I know that I need to prove that:

$$\forall \epsilon >0, \lim_{n \to \infty}\mathbb{P}(|x_n-0|>\epsilon)=0$$

Is there a formal way to prove this? Intuitively, it is clear that $x_n \to 0$ when $n\to \infty$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\mathbb{P} (|X_n| >\varepsilon ) =\mathbb{P} ( X_n =1 ) =\left(\frac{1}{2} \right)^n \to 0,$$ so $X_n \to 0$ in probability.

Let $A_n =\{\omega \in \Omega : X_n (\omega ) =1\}$ and let $A=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty} A_k $ then $\mathbb{P} (A) =0$ and if $\omega\notin A$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty} X_n (\omega ) =0$ thus $X_n \to 0$ almost surely.